# Deleting rows in sql rows based on pair value

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have SQL test table as below:

| Item | Doc_No | Code | Line_Item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc1234 | 101 | 01 |
| 2 | abc1234 | 102 | 01 |
| 3 | def5678 | 101 | 01 |
| 4 | def5678 | 102 | 01 |
| 5 | ghi1234 | 101 | 01 |
| 6 | ghi1234 | 101 | 02 |
| 7 | jkl5678 | 101 | 01 |

I am trying to eliminate rows when duplicate values of **"Doc_No"** has pair values of "101" and "102" in **"Code"** column e.g abc1234 and def5678.

At the same time I want to maintain duplicate values of **"Doc_No"** without the pair value of "101" and "102" in **"Code"** column e.g. ghi1234. Final output as below:

| Item | Doc_No | Code | Line_item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | ghi1234 | 101 | 01 |
| 6 | ghi1234 | 101 | 02 |
| 7 | jkl5678 | 101 | 01 |

I tried to get the rows with duplicate values and exclude them but this will wrongly exclude "ghi1234" and not the final output table I want.

```
    SELECT 
    a.*,
    b.Count_Item
    FROM dbo.test AS a
    LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT Doc_No, COUNT(*) AS Count_Item
        FROM dbo.test
        GROUP BY Doc_No
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS b
    ON a.Doc_No = b.Doc_No
    WHERE b.Count_Item < 2
```

| Item | Doc_No | Code | Line_Item | Count_Item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | jkl5678 | 101 | 01 | 1 |

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: What do you think of below query?

`select doc_no from test
group by doc_no
having count(distinct code) > 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on your construct:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM dbo.test a LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT Doc_No, COUNT(*) AS Count_Item
      FROM dbo.test
      WHERE code IN (101, 102)
      GROUP BY Doc_No
     ) b
     ON a.Doc_No = b.Doc_No
WHERE b.Count_Item < 2 OR Count_Item IS NULL;
```

Note:  This assumes that codes are not duplicated for a doc.

Comment: hi, this work like a charm. May I know what do you mean by "assumes that codes are not duplicated for a doc"? Can give specific example?

Comment: @rain123 . . . If 101 occurred twice for the same doc.

Answer (score 0):

What about [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43085e/1):

```
select *
from test
group by Doc_No, Line_Item
having count(*) = 1
```

or [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43085e/10):

```
select *
from test
where Doc_No not in (
  select Doc_No
  from test
  join test as test2 using (Doc_No)
  where test.Code = 101 and test2.Code = 102
);
```

Comment: I think * cannot be used as not all columns are part of `group by`. Also, this query will  include the `ghi1234` records. @rain123 wants to keep it. It seems @rain123 has only issues with having same doc_no multiple line_items.

Comment: The query I posted yield the "Final output as below" (at least with MySQL).  What did I miss?

Comment: hi @AllanWind, i tried your method with real dataset which i have over 20 columns and it didnt work. The best i can think of is finding column Doc_No value that has pair value of 101 & 102 in Code column then delete/exclude those rows.

Comment: Why did it not work?  I added another  query that gives the same result with test data supplied.